# PHP DateInterval and modify does not advance time

Tags: php, datetime

I have a series of seconds between events. 
I want to calculate the time of the current event.
So I get the time when the process starts and add the seconds.
But this does not advance the minutes for some reason.

I have the following code:

```
$time = '2016-03-10 10:03:07';
$date_obj = new DateTime($time);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    $date_obj->add(new DateInterval("PT20S"));
    // I also tried $date_obj->modify('+ 20 second");
    // but the result is the same.
    $time = $date_obj->format("H:m:s");
    echo $time . "<br>";
}
```

Which outputs:

10:03:27

10:03:47

10:03:07

10:03:27

etc

How can I add seconds so that it advances the minutes instead?

Tried this on my server and this PHP Fiddle, same result: 
https://3v4l.org/oSCsk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are echo'ing the month instead of the minute in this line:

```
$date_obj->format("H:m:s");
```

Try changing it to:

```
$date_obj->format("H:i:s");
```

More info about the accepted date format:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php